# using L_SaveFileOffset to save a Multi-page TIFF file

Tags: c++, leadtools-sdk

I need to save a Multi-page TIFF file using `L_SaveFileOffset` because I need to make sure no other process including Windows itself can access the file in the middle of saving pages and as far as I know `L_SaveFileOffset` is the only API for saving in **LeadTools** that allows saving the image using a file handle. The problem is, no matter what I do, only the last page gets saved. Please Help.

```
HANDLE hFile = ::CreateFile(L"ColorMaps.tif", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if(NULL != hFile)
{
        const wchar_t pathTemplate[] = {L"ColorMap%d.bmp"};
        wchar_t tPath[sizeof(pathTemplate) / sizeof(pathTemplate[0])];
        FILEINFO PageInfo;
        SAVEFILEOPTION so;
        LOADFILEOPTION tlo;
        int i;
        HDC hDc;
        BITMAPHANDLE tBmp;
        __int64 tSize;

        memset(&tlo, 0, sizeof(LOADFILEOPTION));
        tlo.uStructSize = sizeof(LOADFILEOPTION);
        L_GetDefaultLoadFileOption(&tlo, sizeof(LOADFILEOPTION));
        tlo.Flags |= ELO_ROTATED;
        hDc = ::GetDC(NULL);
        tlo.XResolution = ::GetDeviceCaps(hDc, LOGPIXELSX);
        tlo.YResolution = ::GetDeviceCaps(hDc, LOGPIXELSY);
        ::ReleaseDC(NULL, hDc);
        memset(&so, 0, sizeof(SAVEFILEOPTION));
        so.uStructSize = sizeof(SAVEFILEOPTION);
        so.Flags = ESO_INSERTPAGE;

        memset(&tBmp, 0, sizeof(BITMAPHANDLE));
        tBmp.uStructSize = sizeof(BITMAPHANDLE);
        for(i = 1; i < 7; i++)
        {
            ::StringCbPrintf(tPath, sizeof(tPath), pathTemplate, i);
            L_FileInfo(tPath, &PageInfo, sizeof(FILEINFO), 0, &tlo);
            L_LoadBitmap(tPath, &tBmp, sizeof(BITMAPHANDLE), 0, ORDER_RGBORGRAY, &tlo, &PageInfo);
            if (TOP_LEFT != tBmp.ViewPerspective)
                L_ChangeBitmapViewPerspective(NULL, &tBmp, sizeof(BITMAPHANDLE), TOP_LEFT);
            L_SaveFileOffset((L_HFILE)hFile, 0, &tSize, &tBmp, FILE_TIF_PACKBITS, PageInfo.BitsPerPixel, 0, SAVEFILE_MULTIPAGE, NULL, NULL, &so);
            so.PageNumber = i + 1;
        }
    ::CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

The above is just an example and there might be 1000's of pages being saved into the TIFF file.

The problem shows itself if a user opens **Windows Explorer** and navigates to the directory were the file is being saved, you can see that windows is trying to repaint the icon for the file in between each page save and if I use `L_SaveBitmap` or `L_SaveFile`, sometimes they return ***-14*** because windows is reading the file and **LeadTools** cannot get a lock on it.

P.S. `L_SaveFileOffset` returns **1** (*SUCCESS*) for all the pages and I am using **LeadTools Documents imaging version 17.5**.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sam,
One way to have total control over the file handle is to use redirected IO. The code needed to lock the TIFF file for the whole 6 pages will be something like this:

```
// 2 global variables
L_HFILE hFileMyTiff = NULL;
bool reallyClose = false;
L_HFILE EXT_CALLBACK MyOpen(L_TCHAR* pFile, L_INT nMode, L_INT nShare, L_VOID* pUserData)
{
   if(!hFileMyTiff) //only open the file if it's not already open
      hFileMyTiff = (L_HFILE)::CreateFile(pFile, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
   return hFileMyTiff;
}
L_UINT EXT_CALLBACK MyRead(L_HFILE FD, L_UCHAR * pBuf, L_UINT uCount, L_VOID *pUserData)
{
   DWORD dwRead = 0;
   ::ReadFile(FD, pBuf, uCount, &dwRead, NULL);
   return dwRead;
}
L_UINT EXT_CALLBACK MyWrite(L_HFILE FD, L_UCHAR * pBuf, L_UINT uCount, L_VOID* pUserData)
{
   DWORD dwWritten = 0;
   ::WriteFile(FD, pBuf, uCount, &dwWritten, NULL);
   return dwWritten;
}
L_SSIZE_T EXT_CALLBACK MySeek(L_HFILE FD, L_SSIZE_T nPos, L_INT nOrigin, L_VOID* pUserData)
{
   return ::SetFilePointer(FD, nPos, NULL, nOrigin);
}
L_INT EXT_CALLBACK MyClose (L_HFILE FD, L_VOID* pUserData)
{
   if(reallyClose)
   {
      ::CloseHandle(FD);
      hFileMyTiff = NULL;
   }
   else
      ::SetFilePointer(FD, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
   return TRUE;
}
void tst()
{
   const wchar_t pathTemplate[] = {L"ColorMap%d.bmp"};
   wchar_t tPath[sizeof(pathTemplate) / sizeof(pathTemplate[0])];
   FILEINFO PageInfo;
   LOADFILEOPTION tlo;
   int i;
   HDC hDc;
   BITMAPHANDLE tBmp;
   __int64 tSize;

   memset(&tlo, 0, sizeof(LOADFILEOPTION));
   tlo.uStructSize = sizeof(LOADFILEOPTION);
   L_GetDefaultLoadFileOption(&tlo, sizeof(LOADFILEOPTION));
   tlo.Flags |= ELO_ROTATED;
   hDc = ::GetDC(NULL);
   tlo.XResolution = ::GetDeviceCaps(hDc, LOGPIXELSX);
   tlo.YResolution = ::GetDeviceCaps(hDc, LOGPIXELSY);
   ::ReleaseDC(NULL, hDc);

   memset(&tBmp, 0, sizeof(BITMAPHANDLE));
   tBmp.uStructSize = sizeof(BITMAPHANDLE);
   for(i = 1; i < 7; i++)
   {
      ::StringCbPrintf(tPath, sizeof(tPath), pathTemplate, i);
      L_FileInfo(tPath, &PageInfo, sizeof(FILEINFO), 0, &tlo);
      L_LoadBitmap(tPath, &tBmp, sizeof(BITMAPHANDLE), 0, ORDER_RGBORGRAY, &tlo, &PageInfo);
      if (TOP_LEFT != tBmp.ViewPerspective)
         L_ChangeBitmapViewPerspective(NULL, &tBmp, sizeof(BITMAPHANDLE), TOP_LEFT);

      if(i==6) //only allow closing after the last page is saved
         reallyClose = true;
      else
         reallyClose = false;
      L_RedirectIO(MyOpen, MyRead, MyWrite, MySeek, MyClose, NULL); //use our own file I/O functions
      L_SaveFile(L"ColorMaps.tif", &tBmp, FILE_TIF_PACKBITS, PageInfo.BitsPerPixel, 0, SAVEFILE_MULTIPAGE, NULL, NULL, NULL);
      L_RedirectIO(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL); //reset to default I/O so as not affect loading
   }
}
```

Note the use of 2 global variables for simplicity. A cleaner approach might be to define your own data structure and pass its address in the pUserData parameter of L_RedirectIO.
We've tested this solution with v17.5 and verified it's working properly. If it is not suitable for your particular case, please contact LEADTOOLS support service and we'll discuss other alternatives.

**Update**: The latest build of LEADTOOLS v19 now supports appending pages to TIFF files using the L_SaveFileOffset() function.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Just a suggestion, but shouldn't L_SaveFileOffset be fixed so that Multi-page TIFF files can also be saved as a embedded file or to take care of situations like mine?

Comment: We will investigate the function's behavior and discuss it with our development team. If you'd like to be notified of the progress, please open a support case through email or chat and mention this post.

Comment: Do you think this might work for version 14.5 as well?

Comment: By the way, do I have to call the `L_RedirectIO` for each thread?

Comment: Version 14.5 had similar redirected IO functions but some of the data types were different. But we haven't tested this particular code with it and you should keep in mind that older version is now out of production. About L_RedirectIO, it is per thread.